# Highlight some text and download it as image online

Tags: highlighting, online

Till now, I was using [codecogs](https://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php) online editor to quickly get LaTeX images simply by attaching the code at the end of the url like this - [https://latex.codecogs.com/png.latex?\int_{0}&space;^{\infty}](https://latex.codecogs.com/png.latex?%5Cint_%7B0%7D&space;%5E%7B%5Cinfty%7D) it is super versatile.

But my problem occurred when I noticed that highlighting the text is not supported there by using `\bbox` or `\hl`. I want to ask if there is an alternative to these commands or any effective way I can convert LaTeX to image where highlighting is supported.

Comment: Uh, use stanalone class?  [multi=minipage] will allow you to produce several images as separate pages.

Comment: @JohnKormylo can you please explain it a bit more.

Comment: Correction, standalone.  Truth is, I have no idea what codecogs does, but if you want to generate images of equations etc., standalone is the way to go.